# Author List page: Exclude based on last post date not working correctly

Tags: author

Using the following code [from this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71657/author-list-page-exclude-based-on-last-post-date) I thought I had found the answer to my problems of showing authors that have posted in the last 6 months. Unfortunately the way the function checks the date it only seems to block some months and doesn't take in to consideration previous years as it is showing older posts/authors still.

I believe the problem lies in the  `if (6 < (date('n',(time() - strtotime($posts[0]->post_date)))))` with the `n` being the month.

Could anyone assist to correct the lookup so it only shows from the last 6 months?

```
<?php
// Arguments to pass to get_users
// ************* $args = array( 'orderby' => 'post_count', 'order' => 'DSC', 'who' => 'authors' );
// Query for the users
$authors = get_users('orderby=post_count&order=DSC'); //&role=contributor ?>
<?php
// Loop through all the users, printing all of their posts as we go
foreach ( $authors as $author ) {

    // Set up a Loop, querying for all of the current user's posts
    $args = array( 'author' => $author->ID, 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
    $posts = query_posts($args);

    if (6 < (date('n',(time() - strtotime($posts[0]->post_date)))))
        continue; //skips this autor as long as his last post is older than 6 months, be aware that this check uses date function.

 ?>
            <a name="<?php echo $author->user_nicename; ?>"></a>
            <div class="author-posts-wrapper" id="author-<?php echo $author->ID; ?>-posts-wrapper">
                <div class="author-avatar" id="author-<?php echo $author->ID; ?>-avatar">
                    <?php echo get_avatar( $author->ID, 96 ); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="author-posts" id="author-<?php echo $author->ID; ?>-posts">
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $author->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $author->display_name; ?></a></h2>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) :  ?>
                <div class="author-post-list" id="author-<?php echo $author->ID; ?>-post-list">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); // Print whatever we want for each post - for now the title ?>
                    <div class="author-descrip" style="padding-bottom:2px;">
                        <?php the_author_meta("description"); ?></div><br />
          <p><strong>Most recent article: </strong><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
          <p>
            <?php if(get_the_author_meta('user_url')): ?>
                <?= get_the_author_meta('user_url') ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </p>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div><!-- #author-post-list -->
    <?php else: ?>
                    <p style="font-style:italic;">This author has not yet published any posts</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
                </div><!-- #author-posts -->
            </div><!-- #author-posts-wrapper -->
<?php } // End looping over all users ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use something like this:

```
if (strtotime('-6 months', time()) >= strtotime($posts[0]->post_date))
    continue;
```

When using `strtotime`, you actually can *calculate in words*, (e.g., `+1 month`, `-3 hours`).

Comment: This seems to have the opposite effect and show only people who have posted longer than 6 months ago?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't test your whole code, as you can imagine, and mixed the cases here (where a `continue` is used). Now it should do.

Answer (score 3):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can do date math.

```
echo date('Y m d',strtotime('-6 months',time()));
```

So you should be able to do something like...

```
$ptime = strtotime($post->post_date);
$min6m = strtotime('-6 months',time());
if ($ptime <= $min6m) { 
  // echo 'yay';
  continue;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for some reason, I get no results at all

Comment: Not when I test it, and the logic is correct (unless I am going insane). `$ptime` (post time) is greater than or equal to `$min6m` (minus 6 months).

Comment: @s Yes, _our logic_ is correct, but here, a `continue` is used in the _true_ case. Didn't get that before, too. ;)

Comment: Ok... same mistake as @tf. Fixed it. I think. So confused... :)